# How does Xamarin studios for C# work for cross platform apps

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin-studio

1) I just finished my first app in Objective C with Xcode. It's currently "In Review". Eventually I'll want to make an Android port. Can I somehow port Objective C's version of my app into C# version in Xamarin studios for iOS. Then port that iOS version C# Xamararin studios into an Android version of Xamarin studios?

2) I'm confused at how C# Xamarin studios works for cross platforming. Lets say I want to build an new app for iOS and Android. I use C# Xamarin Studios. Do I first create the iOS version in Xamarin studios and then copy/paste the code from iOS version Xamarin Studios with C# into the Android version of Xamarain Studios with C#? If I have it correct, I can use C# for same code for iOS and Android version in Xamarin Studios.

Comment: This is too broad as currently written for Stack Overflow.  Please consider breaking your question down into specific, concrete questions, preferably with code examples.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can't, I'm completely new to Xamarin Studios and C#. I don't know if I should use them or not because I want to make an app for Android and iOS together. So if I can use the same language like C# with Xamarin Studios for both, I want to find out how they work from people who've done cross platforming apps with Xamarin studios using C#.

Comment: An admirable goal and very understandable.  That said, this is not the correct site for that type of question.  My recommendation is to read tutorials on Xamarin and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Xamarin.Forms solution. This create three projects
Android
iOS
PCL

In PCL you can write the cross platform part of your app. In other two projects you have to write platform specific code.

There is a lot of documentation about it.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

Comment: By platform specific code, do you mean I have to know Java for Android? I thought I just had to know C# and that code works for all iOS and Android if I use xamarin studios.

Comment: You have to know c# and .net. If you want to create a PCL cross platform project you have to study Xamarin Forms so you can create with only one code apps for Android, iOS.... If you want to create an android project with full access to Android api you have to use Xamarin.Android and you have to know how works activities, and other android ui controls. The same for iOS

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first quest the "Porting" of your Objective-C to C# would be manual you would basically be rewriting it from scratch using the objective-C as reference.

To work in C# you have 3 options

1. Use the IOS Xamarin Studio App and compile\deploy to IOS.
2. Use the Windows Xamarin Studios and compile\deploy to Android.
3. Use Visual Studio with the Xamarin Plugin either on a Mac or a PC and compile and deploy to IOS,Android and Windows. Note if you use Visual Studio with the Xamarin Plugin on a windows PC to target IOS you still need a Mac located on the same network so VS can automate XCode to do the compile.

You can write everything in 1 set of code in your PCL and get a functional app. However Most apps need Platform specifics that Xamarin hasn't yet wrapped up in a nice neat package for you. In those cases you'll be in one of the platform specific projects tweaking for that platform.